# How do I create a table view with user-clickable values that when clicked, can display meta data?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I am looking for a re-usable method that will enable me to have a table on a page, which will allow me to click a value on that table, which would then display some meta-data related to that object.

For example, let’s assume I have the below table.

[image: Initial View]

If I click the **"Cost of Sales"** value under the **"2014"** column (10,522), another view would appear displaying the meta-data, related to the specific value I've clicked.

Below is an example of what it would look like.

The meta-data view appears to the right and the meta-data is highlighted in yellow.

[image: View with meta-data displayed]

This is basically what I need and I’m not sure what it’s called. I’ve tried Googling for various terms that I thought were related to this but nothing useful seems to come up.

The closest question I could find on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359927/how-can-i-display-a-clickable-table-from-a-nested-array-of-objects), but it's referring specifically to JavaScript and differs to my question. I've also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897311/create-an-html-table-with-clickable-columns) question out but the asker is referring to selecting a whole column using jquery which also differs.

I’m not aware of a specific name or how we refer to this type of functionality.

In short, I could describe this as the creation of an interactive table which allows me to click on a specific value in it, and view the meta-data which has been attached to it.

For the development of this, I’ll be using Visual Studio in a .NET environment with ASP.NET Web Forms. Server-side will be Microsoft SQL Server.

The objective is to end up with a re-usable solution but at this stage it would also be great to get some ideas as to where I can start.

*Photo Source* > https://www.xbrl.org/ixbrl-samples/valeo-income-statement-viewer.html#f-ixv-3

*Please note that the above photo source refers to an iXBRL implementation. Although I am not seeking an iXBRL solution but a more general solution, the photos were chosen to illustrate the requirement.*

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you querying a database? Are the records related to the second set of data with a foreign key?

Comment: The data is coming from a database. The records related to the meta-data (if that is what you mean when you say second set of data) is also from a database with a foreign key.